# My raspberry pi pico gives me a strange error

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny

So I want to turn on a lcd 16x2 using my Raspberry Pi Pico but it can't detect the file requested. First, I upload the file with

```py
import machine
import utime
rs= machine.Pin(16,machine.Pin.OUT)
e = machine.Pin(17,machine.Pin.OUT)
d4 = machine.Pin(18,machine.Pin.OUT)
d5 = machine.Pin(19,machine.Pin.OUT)
d6 = machine.Pin(20,machine.Pin.OUT)
d7 = machine.Pin(21,machine.Pin.OUT)
 
def setCursor(line, pos):
    b = 0
    if line==1:
        b=0
    elif line==2:
        b=40
    returnHome()
    for i in range(0, b+pos):
        moveCursorRight()
def clearScreen():
    rs.value(0)
    send2LCD8(0b00000001)#clear screen
    longDelay(2)#clear screen needs a long delay
    rs.value(1)
def setupLCD():
    rs.value(0)
    send2LCD4(0b0011)
    send2LCD4(0b0011)
    send2LCD4(0b0011)
    send2LCD4(0b0010)
    send2LCD8(0b00101000)
    send2LCD8(0b00001100)#lcd on, blink off, cursor off.
    send2LCD8(0b00000110)#increment cursor, no display shift
    send2LCD8(0b00000001)#clear screen
    longDelay(2)#clear screen needs a long delay
    rs.value(1)

def displayString(row, col, input_string):
    setCursor(row,col)
    for x in input_string:
        send2LCD8(ord(x))
        longDelay(10)
```

Then, I rename it lcd_pico.py
And in the main.py file, I write

```py
from lcd_pico import *
setupLCD()
displayString(1,0,"WELCOME")
displayString(2,0,"TO")
longDelay(4000)
displayString(1,0,"CIRCUIT")
displayString(2,0,"DIGEST")
longDelay(4000)
while(True):
    displayString(1,0,"CIRCUIT")
    displayString(2,0,"DIGEST")
    longDelay(1000)
    clearScreen()
    longDelay(500)
```

And I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "lcd_pico.py", line 26, in setupLCD
NameError: name 'send2LCD4' isn't defined
```

Any ideas of what I can do?

I tried to turn on a lcd using raspberry pi pico. I expected to see some text on the lcd, but, I get a error in the editor Thonny IDE

Answer (score 1):

Obviously because you haven't defined you `send2LCD4()` function.

I guess you used the example from here:

https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-PICO-LCD-not-I2C/

It's defined as:

```
def send2LCD4(BinNum):
    d4.value((BinNum & 0b00000001) >>0)
    d5.value((BinNum & 0b00000010) >>1)
    d6.value((BinNum & 0b00000100) >>2)
    d7.value((BinNum & 0b00001000) >>3)
    pulseE()
```

Comment: I didn't used that example. I actually used this one I think
https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/interfacing-raspberry-pi-pico-with-16x2-lcd-using-micropython

Comment: @ChristianMorogan  At the very end of your page there page section `Code` with a sample with all functions defined. Just import `machine` and `utime` libraries beforehand